# Setting up a MySQL database for use with search functionality

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a very simple MySQL database (articlesDB) with 1 table (articles) and 6 rows that is set up thus:

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id (int) | articletitle | articleorganization | articledate | articleurl |  articletags
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The purpose of the database is to store information about articles as well as to store 'tags' that have been applied to those articles so that the articles are searchable by any combination of queries via a form.

The id auto-increments but the article title, organization, date, url, and tags are all input from an entry form built with PHP.  The problem is that there needs to be a way to enforce the correct tag spelling is applied to the articles, so I was thinking that check boxes would be the way to go. That way only the correctly (and consistently) spelled tags could be applied.

I've found, however, that in order to implement the checkboxes in this manner, I would actually need multiple tables within the database; one for the article data, one for the tags, and one to cross reference the tags with the article data:

// article information

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
id | articletitle | articleorganization | articledate | articleurl
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

// tag information

```
 --------------
id  | articletag
 --------------
```

// article and tag reference

```
 -------------------------------
id  |  articleid  |  articletagid
 -------------------------------
```

After this, though, I'm unsure how to proceed as far as building the logic for the MySQL queries.

I would need to insert data into 3 separate tables, I think, but I've got no idea what exactly needs to go where.

Any help or clues as to where to look are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to have the user type the tags and post the form. In the form treatment file have a SELECT query search for all tags in the Tags table. If they do not match show an error message otherwise create the new entry in the articles table and finally add however many TagOnArticle (or whatever you call it) entry you need.

Here is how I would model this situation:

[image: Database relations]

Now if you want to retrieve all valid tags just use:

```
SELECT tag_name FROM Tag
```

And compare the results to what the user has entered.

Comment: would this method be something that can be done with only one table?

Comment: No that would need the same 3 tables as in your OP which was the same solution I would have gone for myself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to set up a dictionary database. I can not help there. However, you mentioned the logic... I assume you are referring to extracting the closest match?

Unfortunately, the best thing for the job is 'fuzzy logic', (Artificial Intelligence), which is quite tedious (in my opinion). The next best thing would be the [Levenstein](http://kristiannissen.wordpress.com/2010/07/08/mysql-levenshtein/) function.

Comment: At this point I guess it is a matter of how much importance this feature has into the design of your website. If conviviality and user-friendliness are a must then this should be a higher priority than if it is not the case.

Comment: Exactly, as Alexandre said, it all depends on how vital this solution is to the OP.